# how to insert a document without creating new mongodb connection?

Tags: java, multithreading, mongodb

I am trying to develop a java project using mongodb as a database.
I have 2 methods (threaded, without thread)

```
    //myMongoHelper, for connection
    //mydbhelper, threaded insertion

    myMongoHelper m = new myMongoHelper("localhost",27017,"mydb","mycoll");
    int id=100;
    Thread t = new Thread(new mydbhelper(new BasicDBObject()));
    while(id>0){
        t.start();
        t = new Thread(new mydbhelper(new BasicDBObject()));
        id--;
    }
    t.join();
    m.myclose();
```

and

```
        int id =100;
        mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost" , 27017 );
        DBCollection coll = mongoClient.getDB( "mydb" ).getCollection("mycoll");
        while(id>0){
            coll.insert(new BasicDBObject());
            id--;
        }
        mongoClient.close();
```

**$mongod** shell shows  **XX connections now open** while execution of a code, and by default it terminates all connections at the end of java execution.

So I want to know,

1. open connections affects mongodb database and how?
2. is it possible to terminate a thread after insertion to decrease a count of connections?
3. Is threading is better for mongodb operations specially for insertion?

Please improve my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to answer all of them together, every new connection takes huge amount of resource in order to initialize, therefore keep them as low as possible.

Instead of creating a new connection for each thread, use a single connection and distribute your query! you can distribute your queries with this way! also you can use **bulk insert** in order to insert huge amount of docs.

```
    DBCollection coll = mongoClient.getDB( "mydb" ).getCollection("mycoll");
    ArrayList<BasicDBObject> dbos = new ArrayList<BasicDBObject>();
    while(id>0){
        dbs.add(new BasicDBObject());
        id--;
    }
    coll.insert(dbos);
```

Comment: note: my while loop is a dummy method, where I decide values of my document to insert. my values are dependent on time which cant be predicted early.

Comment: as you explained in second para, my threaded method uses myMongoHelper to create only 1 connection. my mydbhelper uses object m for insertion in threaded way. are we thinking same ?? plz provide example code.

Comment: check the code! DBCollection.insert accepts a parameter of type DBObject, List<DBObject> or an array of DBObjects for inserting multiple documents at once.